# Customizing the default profile page of web2py

Tags: customization, web2py, profile

I have customized the auth using the above explained method by Anthony. It is available in the documentation also on the web2py website.
But this is only for the tables in the database. **I wanted to edit the controllers also.** Like the **profile page**, which has all the fields editable by default(except password,which I don't even want to be shown).
I want to use the same page but with little modification. I can't find the controllers to edit them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the scaffolding application, all of the Auth functions are handled by the `user()` function in the `default.py` controller (the associated view is `/views/default/user.html`). The particular Auth action is determined by the first URL arg (i.e., `request.args(0)`), so if you need to run some custom controller or view code for a particular Auth action, you can do something like:

```
if request.args(0) == 'profile':
    [custom code for profile action]
```

For example, to hide the password field, you can do:

```
db.auth_user.password.readable = db.auth_user.password.writable = False
```

Comment: Thanx but I also need to hide some fields,like **password**. Also make some fields writable=False and readable=True.
But I dont know how to set attributes for these fields inside the above code segment you wrote.

Comment: You can set the readable and writable attributes of the Auth tables the same as any other db table. See the updated answer for an example.

Comment: @Anthony How can I use this method to do the following: I have an extra field called X, when the user hits register, I want to check if what he put in this field exist in another pre-populated tabled called Table1. I tried to do if request.args(0)=='register': [check if entry of field X already exists] but it gives an error that field X does not exist.

Comment: @Hans, consider the `registration_onvalidation` callback list: http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/09/access-control#Auth-Settings-and-messages.